# Creating a simple multiplication table

Tags: javascript

Here's the code i've written, which is included in a HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cipars = 10;
var i =0;
document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0" id="Tabula">');
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
for (j=1; j<10; j++) {
document.write("<tr><td>" + i + " x " + j + " = " + j*i + "</td></tr>");    
}
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

What my code does now is that makes a multiplication column more than a table. Can anyone give me a hint how to make it... More like a table? I've explained the problem as good as I can.

Comment: Move your "tr" and "/tr" outside of the j loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to this:

**js**

```
var cipars = 10;
var i =0;
document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0" id="Tabula">');
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
for (j=1; j<10; j++) {
    document.write("<td>" + i + " x " + j + " = " + j*i + "</td>");    
}
   document.write("</tr>");            
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: Not much point posting a fiddle that doesn't work. JSFiddle doesn't allow `document.write`.

Comment: @MattBurland In the fiddle there is a missing `"`, fix that and it will work. `document.write` still works in JSFiddle.

Comment: Anyway removed the fiddle.