# I want to write program to get multiple of 0.10 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to allow user to enter values which are multiple of 0.10 like below  - 
0.10, 0.20, 0.30....1.00, 1.10, 1.20...1.90  etc

I was checking below validation when user entering value in text box

amount % 0.10 == 0

is it correct ? or i need to round reminder ?

Comment: That should work to figure out if the entered value was, in fact, a multiple of 0.1

Comment: When you tried it, did it work?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170181/creating-a-simple-multiplication-table

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the marked question.

Comment: @SaggingRufus this not worked for me.

Comment: Say hello to JS floating math :) `0.50 % 0.10 --->0.09999999999999998`

Comment: @Andrey , yes so reminder will be floating point , so this is wrong logic , what should i do to get multiple of 0.10 ?

Comment: Divide, test to see if the result is a whole number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does modulus operator return fractional number in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966484/why-does-modulus-operator-return-fractional-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use remainder (modulo) on anything but integers.
In order to achieve something like that - you'll have to cast your numbers into integers.

you can do it by simply multiplying their value by 10, i.e:

`1.2 x 10 = 12`

then you can use javascripts [Number.isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) to verify it:

```
function validate(n) {
  let castedNumber = n*10;
  let isInteger = Number.isInteger(castedNumber);
  return isInteger;
}
```